# VK_VOLUME_DOWN cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, media, volume, keycode

I have an app which on button clicks sends messages to a server which then processes these messages into commands. One button is a volume-down button which when clicked send the message "volDown" to the server. I then wish for the server to press the volume down media key found on some keyboards (including mine) to turn down the system volume.

This is the if statement that deals with that message:

```
...
} else if (input.equals("volDown")) {
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_VOLUME_DOWN);
} ...
```

Looking around online I found 'VK_VOLUME_DOWN' is the keycode for this button in Java (could be wrong), but the compiler returns the error message **"VK_VOLUME_DOWN cannot be resolved or is not a field"**. Why can I not use this keycode (I can use others like VK_A fine)?

Answer (score 0):

VK_VOLUME_DOWN is not a constant inside KeyEvent class and therefore you cannot use it. You need to use an extended library for this, something along the lines of HAVi.

Comment: I am facing the same issue when I use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA.How can I resolve this issue?